Is there a way to parse self-contained links inside a PDF through python?
I have a pdf document which contains some internal hyperlinks which lead to different subsections of the same document.
I want to parse these "GoTo" links to create something like a knowledge graph for that document. Is there any way I could read/parse these links?
I have tried using conventional PDF Readers like PyPDF2 or PdfPlumber but since they work as OCR, they cannot fetch those hyperlinks.

Did you look at Extract hyperlinks from PDF in Python ?

Yes, I tried that and i'm able to extract links that lead to external docs or websites. But i'm still unable to read the links that lead to another subsection in the document itself.

Taking the PDF from there: https://hugepdf.com/download/user-manual-43_pdf, which has external and internal likes, you could look up for all subtypes /Links:
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from pprint import pprint

# pdf: https://hugepdf.com/download/user-manual-43_pdf
with open("/tmp/pdf-user-manual.pdf", 'rb') as f:
    pdf = PdfReader(f)

    for i, page in enumerate(pdf.pages):
        if "/Annots" in page:
            for annot in page["/Annots"]:
                subtype = annot.get_object()["/Subtype"]
                if subtype == "/Link":
                    print(annot.get_object())

Out:
{'/BS': {'/W': 0},
 '/Dest': [IndirectObject(24, 0, 4373945936), '/XYZ', 87, 769, 0],
 '/F': 4,
 '/Rect': [278.16, 442.32, 333.81, 457.92],
 '/StructParent': 1,
 '/Subtype': '/Link'}
{'/A': {'/S': '/URI',
        '/Type': '/Action',
        '/URI': 'http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng'},
 '/BS': {'/W': 0},
 '/F': 4,
 '/Rect': [476.68, 395.52, 509.92, 411.12],
 '/StructParent': 2,
 '/Subtype': '/Link'}
{'/A': {'/S': '/URI',
        '/Type': '/Action',
        '/URI': 'http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng'},
 '/BS': {'/W': 0},
 '/F': 4,
 '/Rect': [87.75, 379.92, 162.35, 395.52],
 '/StructParent': 3,
 '/Subtype': '/Link'}


Here is a solution using PyMuPDF:
import pymupdf

internal_links=[]  # list of links to pages in document

# interal link types: GoTo or Named
valid_types = (pymupdf.LINK_GOTO, pymupdf.LINK_NAMED)

doc=pymupdf.open("pdf-user-manual.pdf")
for page in doc:
    links = [l for l in page.get_links() if l["kind"] in valid_types]
    internal_links.extend(links)

Every list item is a dictionary like this one:
{'from': Rect(278.1600036621094, 383.9999694824219, 333.80999755859375, 399.5999755859375),
  'id': '',
  'kind': 1,
  'page': 1,
  'to': Point(87.0, 72.91998),
  'xref': 23,
  'zoom': 0.0}

Link "kinds" are the PDF values for GoTo, GoToR, Named, URI and Launch.
Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.
